# Open user variable location from cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

I created a user environment variable name: teamf and its value as C:\Program Files\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\

This is working since from run I can open the folder by merely typing %teamf%

Now I want to change the directory from root to to this folder location in command prompt (cmd). How can I do that? I have tried:

```
 %teamf% cd teamf
```

but I get errors (see attached image please)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
CD "%teamf%"
```